# Type.GetMethod returning null

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have the following extension method definition:

```
public static IQueryable<T> FindAllOfType<T, TCollection>(this MongoCollection<TCollection> collection)
{
    return collection.FindAs<T>(Query.EQ("_t", typeof(T).Name)).AsQueryable();
}
```

and am trying to use the following code to retrieve the `MethodInfo` so I can invoke the generic method using a type only known at run time (not really relevant):

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(MongoCollection<TCollection>).GetMethod("FindAllOfType", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
```

but it is returning null. I also tried without the generic like this:

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(MongoCollection).GetMethod("FindAllOfType", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
```

but get the same result.

Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Extension methods are by definition not part of the actual class definition, thus cannot be queried through reflection on the class definition.

Comment: You need to query it via the original static class name where the extension method lives

Comment: possible duplicate of [GetMethod for static extension method howto](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338033/getmethod-for-static-extension-method-howto)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Thanks, that was the problem.